# One button to return two random words

Tags: javascript, html, button

I want a button to return two random words into separate boxes.

I've created two buttons to do what I need.

```
<FORM NAME="WordForm">  
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="WordBox" id="wordbox"><BR>
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Click for Random Word 1" onClick="PickRandomWord(document.WordForm);" id="button">
</FORM>

<FORM NAME="WordForm1">  
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="WordBox1" id="wordbox1"><BR>
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Click for Random Word 2" onClick="PickRandomWord1(document.WordForm1);" id="button">
</FORM>
```

I currently have 2 buttons each returning a random word. I'd like one button to do this.

I thought the following would work but it only returns one word;

```
<FORM NAME="WordForm1">  
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="WordBox1" id="wordbox1"><BR>


<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Click for First Idea" onClick="PickRandomWord(document.WordForm); PickRandomWord1(document.WordForm1);" id="button">

</FORM>
</FORM>
```

Comment: post your js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the two calls into a function and call that single function:

```js
function buttonHandler(){
console.log(document.WordForm);
console.log(document.WordForm1);
}
```

```html
<FORM NAME="WordForm">  
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="WordBox" id="wordbox"><BR>
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Click for Random Word 1" onClick="buttonHandler();" id="button">
</FORM>

<FORM NAME="WordForm1">  
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="WordBox1" id="wordbox1"><BR>
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Click for Random Word 2" onClick="buttonHandler();" id="button">
</FORM>
```

I dont know your use-case but i would also advise you to put it all into one form instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put them only in one form I check it out to see what it looks like